# Call method within method Kohana php 2.3.4

Tags: php, methods, kohana

The following code is generating a page not found error with Kohana 2.3.4

```
class Search_Core
{    
    public function result($term)
        {
            $this->search->title = "Search Results";
            $this->search->content = View::factory("search_view");

            $test = $this->pleaseWork("This should be on the screen");
            $this->search->content->test = $test;

            return $this->search;
        }

    public function pleaseWork($word)
        {
            $dude = $word;

            return $dude;
        }

}
```

I've called methods within methods of the same class before, but for some reason this is not working. I can replace the $test variable with something like this:

```
$test = "a bunch of random words";
```

And it will work no problem. I can write something similar outside of Kohana and it will work, but this is not and I can't fgure out why. The $test variable is in the search_view view and as I demonstrated, it works find if I supply a string as opposed to calling a method.

The error is on Kohana.php line# 841.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using

```
$test = Search::pleaseWork("This should be on the screen");
```

instead of the original

```
$test = $this->pleaseWork("This should be on the screen");
```

However, I would still like to know why it didn't work originally. Does it have something to do with this being a library that I'm calling from a controller? I can't imagine why as the $this should be referencing the library.

Comment: try adding a constructor to the library class. if Search::pleasework is working, then presumably the class is being looked through a static reference!

Answer (score 0):

From the name of the class it seems to be a library. you should be calling the library from a controller which renders a view. i dont think a library can render a view.

Comment: The library is being called by a controller. It renders fine when the $test variable is a string.